# Turn off Hard Disk manually from the operating system

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-11, system-administration

I have Windows 10 installed on an SSD, a hard drive for the data.

The hard drive continues to operate for a few minutes before it's turned off by the power options in Windows system.

Windows turns it off automatically (actually stops it from spinning) after x minutes (by power options)

I want to do this manually and turn off the hard drive whenever I want.

Any ideas are welcomed [powershell] [batch] anything.

Comment: What research have you done regarding this, and have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Also, note that Windows turns off the HDD based on it being idle for a given amount of time. So modifying the power settings will still wait for the drive to idle before it actually shuts the drive down, which is probably a good idea anyway so that it doesn't interrupt reads or maintenance. But you can use PowerShell to apply a given power policy, so create a power policy that turns the drive off immediately after it idles, and then user Powershell to apply it or apply a more normal policy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557325/powershell-how-to-set-advanced-hard-disk-power-settings

Comment: what will happen if the hard disk is required when it's being turned off? Just let Windows handle it automatically